# Troubleshooting ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters in a WPF XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and need some help with my XAML file.  I want to include my ViewModel as a `Window.DataContext` file but at runtime, it throws an error regarding the parameters being wrong:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 34 : ObjectDataProvider cannot create
>   object; Type='PrintWindowViewModel'; Error='Wrong parameters for
>   constructor.' MissingMethodException:'System.MissingMethodException:
>   Constructor on type 'BBWindowsUser.PrintWindowViewModel' not found.

The constructor for the ViewModel is:

```
public PrintWindowViewModel(Document pDocument, int pActivePage, List<int> pSelectedPages, bool pPrintingSet, bool pBatch = false)
```

I only need to pass in to the constructor this:

```
PrintWindowViewModel(null, -1, null, false)
```

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BBWindowsUser.PrintWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BBWindowsUser"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Print" Height="150" Width="250">

   <Window.DataContext>
        <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="local:PrintWindowViewModel">
            <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                <x:Null/>
                <sys:Int32>-1</sys:Int32>/>
                <x:Null/>
                <sys:Boolean>false</sys:Boolean>
                <sys:Boolean>false</sys:Boolean>
            </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="{Binding PrintButtonContent}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="70,45,0,0"
                Name="btnPrint"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Height="30"
                Width="100"
                Command="{Binding PrintButtonCommmand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have added an extra /> inside your Constructor parameter, Remove it

```
           <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                <x:Null/>
                <sys:Int32>-1</sys:Int32>
                <x:Null/>
                <sys:Boolean>false</sys:Boolean>
                <sys:Boolean>false</sys:Boolean>                
            </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
```